# P410i: replacement disk disk is not synchronizing; Port ID changed from 1l: to 2l:

Tags: storage, hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

Little problem: Our SA 410i changed the adress of slot 5 of the disk-backplane from Port 1l: to Port 2l:. I don't know why there were no configuration changes made.

We have an HP 380 G6 with an integrated Smart Array 6i Controller. Sometimes we remove one of the mirrored disks we have in Slot 1 and 5 of the right disk backplane. I removed the disk in Slot 1 during normal runtime of the server (to have a backup disk to start the machine in case of any problems) and replaced it with another 72 GB disk. It was NOT synchronizing. The Server then start to gets Problems and some hours later it got totally unaccessible. No Telnet and loc; Port ID changed from 2al login possible.

We restarted the server and got an errormessage that there is no more Logical drive available.
I then reinserted the removed "old" disk and the Server Comes up with the logical drive and the message that there is no disk in the requested Slot Port 1l: Box1: Bay5:. When I look in ACU I can see that the disk in Slot 5 now has the address Port 2l: Box1 Bay5. Therefore the Controller cannot find it on its old place and the synchroization cannot be done.

Does anybody now why the controller changed the address of the disk from port 1l: to port 2l:? And how can I change that back to Port 1l: ?

Thanks for your help!

Bernhard

Comment: There's too much wrong here to even begin addressing the issue...

Comment: Time to restore from backup. I mean, an *actual* backup, not this remove-a-drive-from-the-mirror hokum.

Comment: Hint : removing a working disk is, most definitely, a configuration change.

Answer (score 0):

The HP ProLiant DL380 G6 doesn't have a 6i controller. That was only in the DL380 G4 server from ~2004.

SAS port IDs can change without the array needing reconfiguration. You probably have a read error on the disk that you *didn't* pull.

There may be a SAS cabling issue as well. "Slot 5" == "Port 2l: Box1 Bay5". Please provide the output of the `hpacucli` tool: Run `hpacucli ctrl all show config` and `hpacucli ctrl all show config detail`